# Is it possible to append prefix to files names taken from folder name, automatically? (Windows)

Tags: windows, file, directory, filenames, prefix

I work as technical photographer. I do a lot of photos of particular parts. Each parts get a folder assigned and then I copy photos to the folder.

I would like the names of files (photos) get a prefix which is folder name. Example:
I take 20 photos of part A1. I copy those 20 photos from SD card to my PC to previously created folder named "A1". I would like those 20 files to have names as follows:
A1(1)
A1(2)
A1(3)
[...]
A1(20)

Is it possible to make it automatic? or do it by one click?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need to preserve the original name of the file, or would numbering them fresh be acceptable (e.g. `1, 5, 9` would become `A1 (1), A1 (2), A1 (3)`)?

Comment: I would like to preserve the original name, but if that is not possible, the option with fresh numbering is better than nothing

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to preserve the original numbering, it's as simple as selecting all the files in Explorer, pressing F2 (for rename) and typing in the new name. The files will automatically get non-colliding names in the form of "Name (number)".

This respects the ordering you have selected in Explorer, so if you want the index to increment from older to newer files, for example, just sort the files by date ascending.

This can also be used to preserve the original numbering, but only if there are no gaps and if the numbers start from 1. If you sort the files by name and do the rename trick, they will still be ordered the same as before. If there are gaps, they will not be there anymore with the new file names, though.

One more gotcha is that this only works if all of the files have the same extension. If some are `jpg` and others `png`, for example, each extension will get its own numbering.

If this isn't good enough, you'll either have to use a script, which is  a bit more advanced, or some tool that helps with batch renaming. My favourite has been Total Commander for a long time - in TC, this is as simple as selecting the files you want to rename, pressing Ctrl+M, and changing the file name to something like `A1 ([N])`.